# Android layout adding dynamically with children layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have been trying multiple times, and I can't seem to fix my layout.  Is there a way I can achieve this goal?

Above image is what is happening when having 1 child and 2 children.
The below image is what I want to achieve.

[image: Here are the images]

Here is my parent xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/flow_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="title_container_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flow_title"
            style="@style/TileTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="TEXT" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my child xml that I am adding dynamically

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/primary_icon_section"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/primary_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/small"/>
    <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/primary_sub_text"
            style="@style/Style"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/primary_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            tools:text="Primary sub text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is how I add the child layout:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)parent.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
linearLayout.addView(childView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent linearlayout with id `linear_layout` is set to be in vertical orientation, so your child view will be arranged from top to bottom.

try changing you child xml to

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/primary_icon_section"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/primary_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/small"/>
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/primary_sub_text"
        style="@style/Style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:text="Primary sub text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and your parent.xml as

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/flow_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="title_container_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flow_title"
        style="@style/TileTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="TEXT" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Glad I could help..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things to achieve your goal:

1. Change the `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` from `vertical` to `horizontal`, make the add direction is right.
2. Change your child `LinearLayout`'s `width` to `0dp` and change its `layout_weight` into `1`.

Wish that can help you.